# App permissions for services

Tags: android, android-service

When an application calls a service through an intent, will the permissions that the app has, hold for the service as well? Do I need to explicitly check if permissions are granted and request permissions separately in the service again? I'm using the [Permiso](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2818) library to handle runtime permissions for me/

Comment: if they are in the same application then yes

Comment: The permission in your manifest are for all activities, fragments, services, etc. with the same modul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always Check the permissions before you used it.

1. if the permission given, **Just go forward**.
2. Otherwise, **Stop the service (or) Intimate the requirement of permission** to the App User.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that makes sense